# Can I set a workspace settings in user settings in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know there are two places you can configure settings in VS code. User settings and workspace settings.

Our team occupy the workspace settings already and we maintain it in git for everyone for a project.

So I can't have my specific change there for a project. What I'm trying to do is using different theme for each project. Is there any way to do so? I hope there is a "third" settings only for me for a specific workspace.

Constantly unstaging my change is not an option :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all projects in a [Multi Root Workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) (`.code-workspace` file)

Then you can use the extension [When File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.WhenFile) to change the theme based on file paths. It will change the settings in the `.code-workspace` file